# Can I use an "IN" filter on an Advantage Database Table (TAdsTable)?

Tags: sql, filter, advantage-database-server, where-in

I want to apply a filter to an advantage table using multiple values for an Integer field.

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE FieldName IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Is it possible to do the same on an AdsTable within having to repeat the field using an "OR"?

I want to something like:

```
Filter := 'FieldName IN (1, 2, 3)'
```

Instead of:

```
Filter := 'FieldName = 1 OR FieldName = 2 OR FieldName = 3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the `INLIST` function for this.  That function exists for Visual FoxPro compatibility.  It would look like:

```
Filter := 'InList(FieldName, 1, 2, 3)';
```

However, I do not believe that it is currently optimized to use an index.  So if the table is very large, it will be much more efficient to use the `FieldName = 1 OR FieldName = 2 ...` version of the filter.

Comment: I had used the OR version so I shall leave it as is.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` syntax only works for the SQL, not for the expression engine which is used in filters and indexes.

As already suggested by Mark I would use the `FieldName = 1 OR FieldName = 2 ...` syntax.

More information on the `Advantage Expression Engine` and `Advantage Optimized filters` is in the help:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10.1/master_advantage_expression_engine.htm

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10.1/master_advantage_optimized_filters.htm